# What is an html <ul> (or <ol>) style property to set line spacing between all <li> at once, NOT between the lines WITHIN each <li>?

Tags: html, css, list

There is a closed question whose answer says to add a margin clause to (every) <li>, but I was hoping for a single clause in the <ul> tag to control the entire list.

Comment: Sounds like `margin`... but that's on the `li`s, not the parent.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="m1">
    <li>some text 1</li>
    <li>some text 2</li>
    <li>some text 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.m1 li {
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

It makes all `li` inside `ul class="m1"` with this margins and padding.

Construction

```
xxx yyy { 
   /* some code ... */
}
```

applies to all yyy selectors inside xxx block.

Comment: I do not understand why this correct answer was not accepted and not upvoted?

Comment: @Bharata Thanks! Very cool, it is like hello, from the past ))

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that their is a SPECIFIC style property that you would place on the parent tag to have apply to it's children.

However...

You might want to consider using an "inherit" setting on the "ul". But frankly, I think your best bet is to put the styling on the "li" tag and then those stylings would work for all of the "li" tags you used from that point on.

Or...

If you think you may have additional "li" tags in your page that may utilize different stylings, you could give the "li" tags that you want to have with that certain spacing that I think you're looking for, the same class name. That way, if you wanted other"li" tags to be different, you can separate them from the ones with the same class name. For example...

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">red</li>
    <li class="first">green</li>
    <li class="first">blue</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
<ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}

li.first {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

If you render these bits of code, you will see how the "li" tags with the class of "first" that are with on "ul", are spaced differently than the "li" tags without a class name.

Also, you will notice that this allows you added flexibility, because what if you ran into a situation where you needed to have a "ul" listing group that needed to contain "li" tags with both class types of the "li" tag.

I hope I understood your issue correctly and that my answer helps.

BTW, @Utkanos was correct, from a broader aspect of your issue, you do need "margin" AND you may need "padding", depending on what exactly the end result is that you are looking for.

Let us know what happens!

OH... one more thing!!! You could achieve the effect you're looking for through JavaScript, but I think that would be writing more code and a level of complexity that you really don't need to add.